# Bootstrap Carousel Opacity Images and Text

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, opacity

I am trying to use the Bootstrap Carousel to have background-images at a low opacity with header text at full capacity. I am trying to find out a way to target each slider image without bringing down the text opacity.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Carousel -->
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-      ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>




                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
            <div class="background">
         <img src="img/DSC00154.jpg" alt="first slide" />
                </div>
                <!-- Static Header -->
                <div class="header-text hidden-xs">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2><span>Leadership</span></h2>
                        <br>
                 </div>
                </div><!-- /header-text -->
            </div>

            <div class="item transbox">
                <img src="img/DSC01961.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                <!-- Static Header -->
                <div class="header-text hidden-xs">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2>
                            <span>Mentorship</span>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /header-text -->
            </div><!--item div-->

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/DSC02637.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                <!-- Static Header -->
            <div class="header-text hidden-xs">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2>
                            <span>Wisdom</span>
                        </h2>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /header-text -->
            </div><!--item div-->

             <div class="item">
             <img src="img/DSC00130.jpg" alt="fourth slide">

                 <div class="header-text hidden-xs">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <h2>
                            <span>Community Outreach</span>
                        </h2>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /header-text -->
            </div><!--item div-->
        </div>
        <!-- Controls -->


    </div><!-- /carousel -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.background {
background-image:url(../img/DSC00154.jpg);
border: 2px solid black;
}

div.transbox {
margin: 30px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid black;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

div.transbox p {
margin: 5%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
}
```

Hope there is a way to target this directly without breaking the carousel plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this on your slide using the :before pseudo element. For example, on your item.transbox class, place the css for the background image and the opacity level on the pseudo element, and that will allow your div.item to maintain 100% opacity.

See this bootply for reference: http://www.bootply.com/qoEbTcRDxg